# C++ State Machine / Wpmf-convesion

Tags: c++, avr, atmega2560, avr-gcc, gcc

I'm quite a newbie using C ++. I am trying to implement in C ++, the state machine described in this link for C language:
[https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Coding-State-Machines](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/State-Machines-Event-Driven-Systems).

I have created an Fsm class, which implements the behavior of the state machine, and a Machine class, whose methods will be the states.

The code works, but it generates a warning (-Wpmf-conversions) when I try to save the memory address of a Machine method, in `State state__`

```
class Fsm
{
public:
    typedef void (*State)();
private:
    State state__;
public:
    Fsm(State state);
    void dispatch();
}; 

Fsm::Fsm(State state)
{
    state__ = state ;
} //Fsm

void Fsm::dispatch()
{
    (*state__)() ;
}



class Machine : public Fsm
{
public:
    Machine() : Fsm((State)&Machine::initial) {}       // ctor
};
```

I'm using an Atmega2560, with AVR-GCC compiler.

Comment: For what line of code is the warning generated? Also, why does your Fsm class have two "public" access specifiers. And why type-def (*State)() as void? It could be that I'm forgetting my C++, but I don't see what you're trying  to do here.

Comment: @Paul `typedef void (*State)();` is a typedef for a function pointer to a function with no parameters and a `void` return type.  It is perfectly normal to have multiple public, protected or private sections in a class.

Comment: A "PMF" is a Pointer to a Member Function. In C++ this is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to a member function is not allowed in C++. GCC *can* allow it, but moans at you because it's non-standard.

In C++ the normal way of dealing with the kind of thing you want is through class inheritance.

Typically you would create your base `Fsm` class that implements the basic functionality of your state machine control, then overlay over the top of that (create a new class that inherits the `Fsm` class) another class that implements your specific machine functionality.  You can declare functions in your base `Fsm` class that are *pure virtual* - that is, they exist, but have no body. It's then the job of the child class to actually implement that functionality.  The parent `Fsm` class then knows about those functions and can call them.

So you would have something like:

```
class Fsm {
    public:
        void dispatch();
    protected:
        virtual void initial() = 0;
}; 

void Fsm::dispatch() {
    initial() ;
}



class Machine : public Fsm {
    protected:
        void initial() {
             Serial.println("Here");
        }
}; 

Machine mach;

mach.dispatch(); // --> "Here"
```

`Fsm` knows about `initial()`, but the function hasn't been further defined.  `Machine` implements `initial()`.  You then create an instance of `Machine` which contains everything needed.  Calling `dispatch()` runs the function in the `Fsm` parent class which then calls `initial()` in the child `Machine` class.